# Is there a SQL query to get userwise provisioned account in OIM?

Tags: identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I need a query to check if the account is provisioned to user from database.

Any clues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query to get all the enabled/provisioned accounts to specific user:

```
SELECT OBJ.OBJ_NAME
FROM OBJ,OBI,OIU,OST,USR
WHERE OBJ.OBJ_KEY=OBI.OBJ_KEY
AND OBI.OBI_KEY=OIU.OBI_KEY
AND OIU.USR_KEY=USR.USR_KEY
AND OIU.OST_KEY=OST.OST_KEY
AND OST.OBJ_KEY=OBJ.OBJ_KEY
AND USR.USR_LOGIN='[Insert User Login here]'
AND OST.OST_STATUS IN ('Enabled','Provisioned');
```

Answer (score 1):

Select * from OIU where usr_key = ?;

Join to ORC to see the resource that is provisioned, POL if this is associated with an access policy, OBI to see the approval process.